# Testing grails controller that has a bean from src/groovy

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I have a class in `src/groovy`

```
class Something {
  def foo
}
```

this is in resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    mySomething(Something)
}
```

In my Controller I use this :

```
class MyController {
  def mySomething
  def index () {
    mySomething.foo = "bar"
    render mySomething.foo
  }
}
```

How do I test this?

```
   @TestFor(MyController)
   class MyControllerSpecification extends Specification {
     def "test bean"
     given:
       controller.mySomething = new Something() //is this the best way?
     when:
       controller.index()
     then 
       response.contentAsString == "bar"
   }
```

**Question**

Is this the best way to test this? I've generally seen Mocks created for classes. What is the benefit of the Mocks and should I be using them here?

Answer (score 1):

You use a mock implementation of your service if this is faster than creating a new instance and populating the dependencies.

Sometimes you can have a complex service, that depends on other services and the effort of setting up all required structure is high, then you can use Grails  `mockFor()` method and just mock the specific methods that you will use.

[Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#mockingCollaborators) show you how to mock classes that will be used in your unit test.

In your example I don't see advantages, since Something is just a holder for foo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defineBeans` (refer [Testing Spring Beans](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/guide/single.html#testing)) while `setUp` or `given` since `Something` has been declared as a `bean` inside `resources.groovy`

```
defineBeans{
   mySomething(Something){bean ->
      //To take care of the transitive dependencies inside Something
      bean.autowire = true 
   }
}
```

Comment: +1. `defineBeans` is another way to go, but before Grails 2.2.2,if you use `grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean()` your mocked beans wasn't registered in the main context.

Comment: I remember your [suggested improvement](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9980) my friend. Thanks for bringing that up. :)

Comment: I hardly fetched the bean again from the `mainContext` once it was assigned to `controller` members. Since in this case it in `src/groovy` I assume no transactions involved, but yes the improvement is helpful.